# How key/value pairs are stored in Redis

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache, redis-cache

We use Elasticache Redis node to store data.

All keys have same format:
- Key is md5 hash - 128 bits (16 bytes, 32 string characters bytes).
- Value is time stamp string - 19 bytes.
In total, key size is `32+19=51 bytes`

We have `84 917 361` million of keys.
I assume, total memory, that Redis shell consume, is close to `84917361*51 = 4.03 gb`.

Actually, it takes `11.07 gb`.
Output of `info` command:
`used_memory_human:11.07G`

1. On what is spent rest of the memory, `7 gb`?
2. Is there a way to store `md5` as 16 bytes hash, not string with 32 characters?

Thanks, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You might be interested in [this article](https://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization), especially the part about the memory impact of keys versus hashes.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin Christopher Henry , I will implement suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On what is spent rest of the memory, 7 gb?

Short answer: **Redis does NOT store key and value as raw string**.

In fact,

1. the key is wrapped into a `sdshdr` structure (for the latest version, it's a more compact structure), which has some overhead, e.g. the length of the string.
2. the value is wrapped into a `redisObject` structure, which also has some overhead, e.g. object encoding, refcount.
3. There're also other overhead when Redis insert a  pair into a dict, e.g. the `next` pointer and `key` pointer in a `dictEntry` structure.

All of these overhead consumes the rest of memory.

In order to make it's more memory efficient, you can refer to the article that @Kevin Christopher Henry mentioned (small hash can save lots of `redisObject` overhead, and can use `ziplist` to make elements more compact in memory).

> Is there a way to store md5 as 16 bytes hash, not string with 32 characters?

**Use a hash function, such as Murmurhash, to create a digest for each md5 string**.

In this way, you can get a 8 bytes (64 bits) digest. However, you cannot get the raw md5 string from the `Murmurhash` digest. So if you DO **NOT** care the value of md5, you can take this method.

Comment: Thanks @for_stack, that is what I was looking for. I will try to use `Murmurhash` or `crc32` as hash value.